# Retarget to WindowsPhone 8.1 - Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, json.net, nuget, upgrade

My solution builds without problems/errors until I upgraded my WindowsPhone 8.0 Project with the option 'Retarget to WindowsPhone 8.1'.

I get the following error:

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.xml'. Source files: 
>   C:[mypath]\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.xml
>   C:[mypath]\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.xml

I tried following without success:

- Remove all Json references with nuget and manually and reinstall it
- Clean solution, rebuild solution, restart VisualStudio
- Delete bin and obj Folders and rebuild solution

Only thing that helped is to set 'local copy' for the Json reference to false. But thats not a clean solution in my case...

Can someone explain me whats going wrong?

**Edit**

Another solution for that Problem: Delete the XML-Files in the 'packages' folder or rename them. But it's also not a clean solution...